# CUDA_npp_LIBRARY error with cmake 2.8 and CUDA v 5.5

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv, cuda, cmake, npp

I am trying to build a solution in Visual Studio 2010 and to do so had to setup cmake 2.8, opencv and CUDA v5.5 for supporting files. While doing a cmake build I get the following error.

> CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to        NOTFOUND.Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
>   CUDA_npp_LIBRARY (ADVANCED)linked by target "opencv_gpu" in directory D:/opencv/modules/gpu

On looking in the CUDA directories I found that the npp library has been split into three separate libraries: npps.lib,nppi,lib and nppc.lib. I tried putting all three files in the CUDA_npp_LIBRARY path but I still get the same error. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

CUDA 5.5 support was added in 2.4.6 version. Please use the latest code. Also I recommend to use latest CMake version.